# adding zoom in zoom out function

Tags: android, zooming, pinch

i have written this code for loading multiple of images from url one by and swiping effect on images.....but now i need to zoom in & out the images on finger spread...i think pinch zoom...i am unable to implement the zooming function..also confused about where to place the function or i should make a class for this..please help....thanks and regards..

this is my code:

```
package com.conn;

import android.R;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.GestureDetector;
import android.view.GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ViewFlipper;

public class swipe_touch extends Activity {
    private static final String LOGID = "CHECKTHISOUT";

    private static final int SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE = 120;
    private static final int SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH = 250;
    private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY = 200;
    private GestureDetector gestureDetector;
    View.OnTouchListener gestureListener;

    private Animation slideLeftIn;
    private Animation slideLeftOut;
    private Animation slideRightIn;
    private Animation slideRightOut;
    private ViewFlipper viewFlipper;
    int i;
    ImageView[] img = new ImageView[24];

    String message = "Initial Message"; 
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
//        setContentView(R.layout.main);
      //Set up viewflipper
        try
        {
        viewFlipper = new ViewFlipper(this);   
        for(i=1;i<=3;i++)
        {
        Log.i("for","loop");
        j_comm_func funs = new j_comm_func();
        BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions;
        bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        bmOptions.inSampleSize = 1;
        Bitmap bm = funs.LoadImage("http://65.175.77.34/newsnow/2462011/largest3/2462011-md-hr-"+i+".jpg", bmOptions);
        img[i] = new ImageView(this);
        img[i].setImageBitmap(bm);
        viewFlipper.addView(img[i]);

        }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Log.i("error",e.getMessage());
        }


        //set up animations
        slideLeftIn = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.slide_out_right);
        slideLeftOut = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.slide_in_left);
        slideRightIn = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.slide_in_left);
        slideRightOut = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.slide_out_right);


        //put up a brownie as a starter
        setContentView(viewFlipper);

        gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(new MyGestureDetector());
    }

    public class MyGestureDetector extends SimpleOnGestureListener {
        @Override
        public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
            try {
                if (Math.abs(e1.getY() - e2.getY()) > SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH)
                    return false;
                // right to left swipe
                if(e1.getX() - e2.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
                    Log.v(LOGID,"right to left swipe detected");
                    viewFlipper.setInAnimation(slideLeftIn);
                    viewFlipper.setOutAnimation(slideLeftOut);
                    viewFlipper.showNext();
                    setContentView(viewFlipper);

                } // left to right swipe 
                else if (e2.getX() - e1.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
                    Log.v(LOGID,"left to right swipe detected");                    
                    viewFlipper.setInAnimation(slideRightIn);
                    viewFlipper.setOutAnimation(slideRightOut);
                    viewFlipper.showPrevious();
                    setContentView(viewFlipper);

                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // nothing
            }
            return false;
        }
    }



    // This doesn't work
    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if (gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event)){
            Log.v(LOGID,"screen touched");
            return true;
        }
        else{
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: do you want to use the scaleDetector which is for froyo devices 2.2 and higher or something compatible with 2.1 devices?

Answer (score 0):

Load the images in a WebView, which has the pinch to zoom functionality built in.